# How to search date in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Hi I have this code working when searching a string I just use .contains but
what will I use if I will search Date?

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            domescticwastes = domescticwastes.Where
                    (s => s.Location.Contains(id) ||
                     s.Name.Contains(id) ||
                     s.Address.Contains(id) ||
                     s.Contact.Contains(id) ||
                     s.AccNo.Contains(id) ||
                     s.Contractor.Contains(id));
        }
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure why anyone would search a date string for an ID... seems extremely weird... but if you must do that, I suggest you simply convert the date to a string and search the string, e.g. using `ToString()` or `string.Format()`.

Comment: I just told you Jose. The question I am asking is *why* are you searching a date string for an ID?

Comment: oh i see, "id" is just the name of my input box in .cshtml, because im trying to make a search using date range but i dont know how :)

Comment: I see. So instead of searching a date, you want to search *for* a date, in a list of objects, where one of the properties is a `DateTime`. Is that right?

Comment: @JohnWu, do you have an Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC app with date range search? if you mind :) i having a hard time to make one.

Comment: yes @JohnWu exactly!

Comment: Have you tried something like `s.MyDate >= new DateTime(startYear, startMonth, startDay) && s.MyDate <= new DateTime(endYear, endMonth, endDay)`?

Comment: i will try that one.